# In Spring-data-Mongodb, I'm not able to specify limit values to limit the number of results

Tags: mongodb, limit, spring-data

Here is the Spring Repository class

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository {

```
@Query(value = "{location :{ $nearSphere :{$geometry : {type : \"Point\", coordinates : [?1, ?0] }, $maxDistance :?2}}")
List<User> search(float latitude, float longitude, float radius, int limit);
```

}

I'm not able to use limit() function to limit total number of results returned by the search function.  I've tried appending limit() in all places within @Query annotation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use limit and skip in MongoRepository<Customer,String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71887036/use-limit-and-skip-in-mongorepositorycustomer-string)

Answer (score 4):

Using the repository abstraction allows you to add a `Pageable` parameter (will be automatically picked up for query execution) to the method signature.

```
@Query(value = "{location :{ $nearSphere :{$geometry : {type : \"Point\", coordinates : [?1, ?0] },  $maxDistance :?2}}")
List<User> search(float latitude, float longitude, float radius, Pageable page);
```

Once you've got that in place you can simply call it via

```
//get the first 10 matching results
userRepository.search(37.802066, -122.377347, 10, new PageRequest(0,10));
```

You can find some more samples for [special parameter bindings](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) and [geo queries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.geospatial) in the reference manual.

Comment: The Pageable should be created like this (constructor is protected in current API):
PageRequest.of(0, 10);